# PHP, linking variables to a specific date in a form

Tags: php, forms, validation, variables

How can I assign a variable to a specific date for use in a form?

I want a warning to appear when the user tries to book too many a people on a specific date. I started writing this code but didn't know where to go from there:

```
<?php  

    $spaces = 20;
    $num_people = GET('#people');
    $message = "Unfortunately we don't have this many spaces avilable on this date. We have a maximum of $spaces.";

    if($spaces < $num_people) {
      echo $message;
    }
```

?>

How could I assign the value $spaces to a specific date and link it into a form? Here is the form:

```
<form method="post">
    Name:<br>
    <textarea id="name"></textarea><br>
    <br>
    Date leaving:<br>
    <br>
    <textarea id="date"></textarea><br>
    <br>
    How many people?:<br>
    <textarea id="people"></textarea><br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit">
```

Comment: You would need to store the date and spaces in that date into a database table.. And after that you can validate the user input values from the same table.

Comment: Use some jQuery date picker plug in and specify the value of $spaces in the same.

Comment: Cheers guys. I created a table in PHPmyadmin with id, name, date, people. How do I link this up with the form so it can pull the information and implement it into the PHP code to make the warning?

Answer (score 0):

`$num_people = GET('#people');`

This line should be

`$num_people = $_GET['people'];`

and

`<textarea id="people"></textarea><br>`

shoul be

`<textarea id="people" name="people"></textarea><br>`

And your method ahould be `GET`. Since you are sending `GET` request.

Your code should look like this:

```
<?php  

if(isset($_GET['people'])){

$spaces = 20;
$num_people = $_GET['people'];
$message = "Unfortunately we don't have this many spaces avilable on this date. We have a maximum of $spaces.";

if($spaces < $num_people) {
  echo $message;
}

}
?>  
<form method="get" action="">
Name:<br>
<textarea id="name"></textarea><br>
<br>
Date leaving:<br>
<br>
<textarea id="date"></textarea><br>
<br>
How many people?:<br>
<textarea id="people" name="people"></textarea><br>
<br>
<input type="submit">
```